# How can I create a function that alters the default value of an enumerator?

Tags: c, enums, enumeration, enumerator

how's everyone doing?

so I created an enumerator that contains 4 values:

gamestates.h:

```
#ifndef GAME_STATES_H
#define GAME_STATES_H

enum GAME_STATE { MAIN_MENU, RUNNING, PAUSED,
                   GAME_OVER, EXIT };

void updateCurrentGameState(void);

enum GAME_STATE getCurrentGameState(void);

void setCurrentGameState(void);

#endif
```

and i successfully implemented the idea of getting the current game state but I have no idea on how can I accomplish setting it outside the gamestates.c class:

```
#include "gamestates.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>


GAME_STATE = MAIN_MENU;

void updateCurrentState(void){

}

enum GAME_STATE getCurrentGameState()
{
    return GAME_STATE;
}

// PSEUDO CODE
void setCurrentGameState(variable passedGameState){
    GAME_STATE = passedGameState;
}
```

i basically want to call `setCurrentGameState(GAME_OVER)` outside the `gamestates` class, is that possible?

thanks

Comment: That enumerator contains 5 values, not 4 as you claim.

Comment: `gamestates.c` is a file, not a class.  C doesn't have classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a global variable used in your C file you can, do this (note: you should make this variable static):

```
//gamestate.c
static enum GAME_STATE gameState = MAIN_MENU
void setGameState(enum GAME_STATE state){
    gameState = state;
}
enum GAME_STATE getGameState(){
    return gameState;
}
```

If you don't have it in your C file you can pass a pointer to it:

```
void setGameState(enum GAME_STATE *gameState, enum_GAME_STATE state){
    *gameState = state;
}
```

and you can simply get its value by referencing it obviously, though this is useless in most cases because you can just do `*gameState = state` yourself instead of calling a function to do it.